# Result of 'HymnLyrics' initializer is unused

Tags: button, struct, swiftui

I have the following error in my code. Please help me why I cannot use my HymnLyrics() struct inside button action. It works for NavigationLink of destination but I don't wanna use it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var tappingSwitches: TapToggle

    let zoLyrics: [Lyric] = LyricList.hymnLa.sorted { lhs, rhs in
        return lhs.zoTitle < rhs.zoTitle
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(zoLyrics, id: \.id) { zoLyric in
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        
                        HymnLyrics(lyrics: LyricList.hymnLa)// Here is the error, I can use directly by using NavagationLink

                        self.tappingSwitches.isHymnTapped.toggle()

                    }, label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(zoLyric.zoTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("bTextColor"))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)

                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(zoLyric.number)")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("bTextColor"))
                        }
                    })
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you want, what do you try to achieve?

Comment: I have a Lyric() which is a custom list created by myself. HymnLyrics() is a struct that will display correctly on the canvas. Here, every time I click on Text(zoLyric.zoTitle), I want to jump to HymnLyrics() and display the exact number. Please see all the code it is kind of confusing but my main goal is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060444/passing-array-of-data-into-another-array-of-data/69060630#69060630

Comment: The `action` closure is for executable code, for example presenting a view. `HymnLyrics(lyrics: LyricList.hymnLa)` is *just* a view. What do you want to do with it? Present it in a `.sheet`? Or push it via `NavigationLink`?

Comment: @Lian sorry, it's 12:00 am here and I'm about to sleep

Comment: It's alright. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "but I don't wanna use it" - why? Are you trying to use it in a `.sheet` like @aheze suggested? Without more information, this is probably not answerable.